# Spring Javaconfig inter-bean dependencies

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, spring-boot, spring-java-config

Browsing the Spring Javaconfig reference documentation
http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html
I found some confusing parts...

Under section ***"5.12.4 Using the @Configuration annotation"*** it says:

*"When @Beans have dependencies on one another, expressing that dependency is as simple as having one bean method call another:*

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public Foo foo() {
        return new Foo(bar());
    }
    @Bean
    public Bar bar() {
        return new Bar();
    }
}
```

*In the example above, the foo bean receives a reference to bar via constructor injection."*

Well, if everything is stateless, it might not matter much, but if you have the config above, and then in your application do:

```
@Autowired 
private Foo foo;

@Autowired 
private Bar bar;
```

checking the hashCodes of the beans, it turns out, that your private variable **bar** will refer to a *different instance* of **Bar** than the one used by **foo**,
which is probably not what you expect, right?

I would say the normal pattern should rather be:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public Bar bar() {
        return new Bar();
    }
    @Autowired Bar bar;
    @Bean
    public Foo foo() {
        return new Foo(bar);
    }
}
```

Now, when you autowire both beans in your app, you will only create a single instance of Bar.

**Am I missing something, or am I correct that the documentation is flaky here?**

Then, further down, under section ***"Further information about how Java-based configuration works internally"*** 
it looks like they try to "clarify" this issue:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public ClientService clientService1() {
        ClientServiceImpl clientService = new ClientServiceImpl();
        clientService.setClientDao(clientDao());
        return clientService;
    }
    @Bean
    public ClientService clientService2() {
        ClientServiceImpl clientService = new ClientServiceImpl();
        clientService.setClientDao(clientDao());
        return clientService;
    }
    @Bean
    public ClientDao clientDao() {
        return new ClientDaoImpl();
    }
}
```

Now, unfortunately, this configuration, won't even load at runtime, because there are 2 beans of the same type, ClientService, with no distinguishing properties, so get exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type [.....] is defined: 
expected single matching bean but found 2
```

But even if we change the example slightly, and give the first 2 beans different types,

```
@Bean
public ClientService1 clientService1() {...clientDao()...}
@Bean
public ClientService2 clientService2() {...clientDao()...}
@Bean
public ClientDao clientDao() {
    return new ClientDaoImpl();
}
```

this is still incorrect, since -- contrary to what the text claims -- we would still create 3 different instances of ClientDaoImpl,
when autowiring all 3 beans.

**Again, am I totally missing something, or is the documentation really as bad as it seems to me?**

**EDIT:** Added a demo that will demonstrate the issue I see:

https://github.com/rop49/demo

A bean **ServiceA**, 
and two beans **ServiceB1**, **ServiceB2** that constructor-injects **ServiceA**.

Then two test-classes **Config01Test** and **Config02Test** that are identical except for the configurations. The first test PASSES, the second FAILS because of uniqueness-asserts.

Comment: Why do you think you'll get different `Bar` objects?

Comment: I made a small test, and check the hashCodes in the beans. They are different. I clarified this in the question above, thanks.

Comment: Any way you could post a simple running example on GitHub, possibly with Spring Boot? I've never seen this behavior, and it's a bug if it's really happening.

Comment: Also, could you try setting an instance field from a static counter? This might just be an issue with Spring proxying.

Comment: I added a demo testcase at the end of my question above.

Comment: I just made another commit, to use unique UUID's instead of hashCode(). Still same issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check that you have `@Configuration` annotations on your configuration class. With your demo at least they are missing from the `Config01` and `Config02` classes. If I add them to those classes the tests pass.

Comment: Aah, great I got that sorted out :) Thanks Phil!

Comment: As a side-note... would it make sense to have Spring reject \@SpringApplicationConfiguration of classes that do not have the \@Configuration annotation? Or would it ever be a valid usecase to allow this?

Comment: Unfortunately it would break back-compatibility. See the lite-beans section here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-basic-concepts

Answer (score 0):

I've not test the example myself, This should make sure that you have only one instance of Bar in the complete application context

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public Foo foo(Bar bar) {
        return new Foo(bar);
    }
    @Bean
    public Bar bar() {
        return new Bar();
    }
}
```